# New employee: interested in internal position within the company

Tags: recruitment, job-change, internal-transfer, netherlands

I live in Europe. I started working for a large company about 2 months ago via a recruitment agency. While browsing around LinkedIN, I stumbled on an interesting position for a different department in the same company, but in a different city. I'm not quite sure about how much overlap there is between the other department and the one I currently work for. But I wouldn't be surprised if the recruiter/manager for this position and my current manager knew each other.

Would I have broken any important rules by reaching out to the recruiter and/or manager for this other position and proposing myself as a potential candidate? I know exactly who they are and could "serendipity-call" them via our internal Microsoft Teams database. Would they typically keep my application confidential? Would it even matter if they didn't? What is the proper way of expressing interest in an internal position within the company?

Comment: *What is the proper way of expressing interest in an internal position within the company?* There should be internal documentation of your employer's policy for this somewhere like in the employee handbook. However, you should not be surprised if it turns out they don't allow internal transfers until you've been in a position for a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's unlikely the application will be kept secret. Maybe things are a bit different in the Netherlands, I don't know.

It's not in the company's interests to have employees secretly meeting managers and trying to orchestrate transfers behind the scenes. It's far better for transfers to be managed in some way.

2 months is not a lot of time at all. Personally I would refrain from trying to internally transfer so soon. It makes you look easily distracted or flighty.

Comment: *It makes you look easily distracted or flighty* The reality is that my current position is not as fulfilling as I thought it would be. I bring 4 years of software development experience to the table and this is not being exercised in the work I'm currently carrying out. I asked my immediate colleagues, and they have already explained that they don't need help with the software development (even though they have less experience in this area than I do, I've seen their code).

Comment: I guess my question to you is, wouldn't being *easily distracted or flighty* the adequate response to not feeling fulfilled with my current work?

Comment: @user32882 are you still on probation period? Companies often forget that probation is a 2 way street. So if you are on probation it just means that you didnt think the job was for you, thats it.

Comment: I'm an immigrant from a 3rd world country with a temporary residence status. I can't just walk out like that for the time being...

Comment: If that is the case @user32882 then I would raise those issues with your manager (rather than just colleagues) first of all. This will address the concern that you haven't given them a chance to fix the issues before trying to jump ship to a different team

Comment: @mattfreake You're right. In my experience however managers can't really do much to fix anything. It's either a good fit or it isn't, and alternative work exists, or it doesn't....

Comment: In my experience, managers mainly have the power to hire and fire employees. Addressing issues like this with your manager is typically just a good reason for them to start thinking about the latter option...

Comment: If that is the case, I'm not sure approaching another team will go that we'll either, but it all depends on the company